# Is there a possibility to update the value that was passed by a segue into a second view?

Tags: ios, nstimer, segue

I passed data trough a segue using the prepareForSegue()-method by clicking on a button. Now, I can use it within the second view to print it into a label or something like that. The problem is that the said value changes every few seconds, but the second view only shows the initial value (because the event occurs only one time!). I thought about a timer, but I'm not really sure if this could help me to fix this problem. Does someone know a possibility to realize this kind of updating of data using a segue? If not, how would you like to fix this? I need a hint for a basic approach.

Thanks in advance!

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"tab"]){

    NSNumber  *sliderNumber = [self.dic objectForKey:@"slider"];
    NSString *convertSliderNumber = [sliderNumber stringValue];

    TabBarViewController *tabBar = [segue destinationViewController];

    [tabBar setLabelString:convertSliderNumber];

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an object that contains that value and give the segued viewController a pointer to that object, then any value you update in that object will be updated in both viewControllers.

Comment: Oh, nice idea. I haven't thought about that. Thanks, i'll try to implement it. :-)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I edited my question to demonstrate the problem. I think I already use pointers and so I don't know how to change. The object in the dictionary belonging to the key "slider" is the value I need to use in the second view.

Comment: The problem is that you are creating that String (convertSliderNumber) inside of that method, so you have no access to it anywhere else in that class and hence cannot change it. You need to have a reference to it in the class and change it whenever the dict's slider key is changed.